# Document not saving after finding and modifying in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a route to remove a team and all requests to join that specific team, which is nested in a JoinTeamRequests array in the UserProfiles. The idea is to remove all traces of invites to that team once it has been deleted. I am using the MEAN stack. I am still new at this so any other advice or suggestions would be great.

here is my route:

```
 //Remove a specific team
    .delete (function (req, res) {

    //Delete the team - works
    TeamProfile.remove({
        _id : req.body.TeamID
    }, function (err, draft) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
    });

    UserProfile.find(
        function (err, allProfiles) {

        for (var i in allProfiles) {
            for (var x in allProfiles[i].JoinTeamRequests) {
                if (allProfiles[i].JoinTeamRequests[x].TeamID == req.body.TeamID) {

                    allProfiles[i].JoinTeamRequests.splice(x, 1);
                    console.log(allProfiles[i]); //logs the correct profile and is modified
                }
            }
        }   
    }).exec(function (err, allProfiles) {
        allProfiles.save(function (err) { //error thrown here
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({
                message : 'Team Successfully deleted'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

However, I get an error: TypeError: allProfiles.save is not a function.

Why is it throwing this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341340/nodejs-mongoose-saving-model-undefined-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is more common to perform search in next form:

```
UserProfile.find({'JoinTeamRequests.TeamID': req.body.TeamID})
```

Secondly, after execution you have to check if returned array is not empty:

```
if(allProfiles && allProfiles.length) {

}
```

I think it could be possible to execute this in one statement, but for now, try the next chunk of code:

```
   UserProfile.find({'JoinTeamRequests.TeamID': req.body.TeamID}).exec(function (err, users) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end(err);
        }
        if(users && users.length) {
            users.forEach(function(user) {
                user.JoinTeamRequests.remove(req.body.TeamID);
                user.save(function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        return res.end(err);
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: This seems to have removed the whole UserProfile if it contained the JoinTeamRequest. It is only meant to remove the request object in the JoinTeamRequest array.