# Save function coming up as not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an MEAN API, where I'm trying to updated an object nested in my document. First I do a query to find a user Profile, then I set the properties in the subdocument/nested object.

I have done the same implimentation on another end point, which works. But for  some reason I'm getting the following error in the console when this endpoint is called:

"TypeError: profile.save is not a function"

Here is the code that should update the nested "Shared" object:

```
  Profile.find({'contacts.emails.email_address':req.body.invited_email}, function(err, profile){
    if(err)


          profile[0].contacts.shared.first_name = req.body.first_name;
          profile[0].contacts.shared.last_name = req.body.last_name;
          profile[0].contacts.shared.initial = req.body.initial;
          profile[0].contacts.shared.linkedin = req.body.linkedin;
          profile[0].contacts.shared.facebook = req.body.facebook;
          profile[0].contacts.shared.pinterest = req.body.pinterest;
          profile[0].contacts.shared.twitter = req.body.twitter;
          profile[0].contacts.shared.emails = req.body.emails;
          profile[0].contacts.shared.phones = req.body.phones;
          profile[0].contacts.shared.addresses = req.body.addresses;


          profile.save(function(err){
            if(err)
              res.send(err);
            res.json(contact);
          });

    }
```

I'm still fairly new to developing APIs with Node/Express and Mongo, so I'm sure this is a simple thing I'm just missing.

Appreciate any help!!

Updated:

Here is my "profile" schema. The "profile: contacts: shared" sections shows what information the owner of the profile is sharing and the section that my code is trying to update.

```
{  
   "_id":"59474bc3478604a75e1980e2",
   "initial":"D",
   "last_name":"Smith",
   "first_name":"John",
   "owner_id":"59474b92478604a75e1980e1",
   "__v":25,
   "linkedin":"jsmith",
   "facebook":"jsmith",
   "contacts":[  
      {  
         "shared":{  
            "last_name":"Smith",
            "first_name":"John",
            "_id":"5949fc8859e8b0c7dd0ca666",
            "businesses":[  

            ],
            "addresses":[  
               {  
                  "_id":"59474c5c478604a75e1980ea",
                  "address_type":"personal",
                  "zip":"98119",
                  "state":"WA",
                  "city":"Seattle",
                  "address":"102 Hallo Drive"
               }
            ],
            "phones":[  
               {  
                  "_id":"5947521e20b33aa8946c9734",
                  "phone_type":"home",
                  "phone_number":"2067879999"
               }
            ],
            "emails":[  
               {  
                  "_id":"59474c1f478604a75e1980e8",
                  "email_address":"looking@filter.com",
                  "email_type":"business"
               }
            ]
         },
         "last_name":"Jones",
         "first_name":"Tom",
         "_id":"5949fc8859e8b0c7dd0ca664",
         "businesses":[  

         ],
         "addresses":[  

         ],
         "phones":[  

         ],
         "emails":[  
            {  
               "email_type":"home",
               "email_address":"tsom@jones.com",
               "_id":"5949fc8859e8b0c7dd0ca665"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "addresses":[  
      {  
         "address":"102 Hallo Drive",
         "city":"Seattle",
         "state":"WA",
         "zip":"98119",
         "address_type":"personal",
         "_id":"59474c5c478604a75e1980ea"
      }
   ],
   "phones":[  
      {  
         "phone_number":"2067879999",
         "phone_type":"home",
         "_id":"5947521e20b33aa8946c9734"
      }
   ],
   "emails":[  
      {  
         "email_type":"personal",
         "email_address":"chris@chrisnakea.com",
         "_id":"59474c01478604a75e1980e6"
      },
      {  
         "email_type":"business",
         "email_address":"smart@guy.com",
         "_id":"59474c0e478604a75e1980e7"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: should be `profile[0].save` but if your `email` is unique then you can use `findOneAndUpdate` function

Comment: Moreover you should be using `.findOne()` when you mean to return only one.

Comment: Duplicate of [Nodejs Mongoose Saving model undefined is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341340/nodejs-mongoose-saving-model-undefined-is-not-a-function)

Comment: callback function need to get `contact`, i.e `profile.save(function(err, **contact**){
            if(err)
              res.send(err);
            res.json(contact);
          });`

Comment: Shaishab Roy, thanks for the response. I initially find the parent document with the unique email. How would you do the secondary query with the "findOneAndUpdate" that then finds the specific contact in the contact array? And then update the "Shared" object for that contact? If you could refer me to a code example, I would be VERY grateful to see the implimentation.

Comment: @cnak2 could you please show your full data structure and and what information want to update ?

Comment: There you go Shaishab. I added an update and a bit more description to the  original post. Appreciate your help.